# How to set auto-start permission programmatically in Android?

Tags: java, android

I tried many ways to set autostart permission automatically, But nothing works is there any ways to set it.
I tried

```
try {
        Intent intent = new Intent();
        String manufacturer = android.os.Build.MANUFACTURER;
        if ("xiaomi".equalsIgnoreCase(manufacturer)) {
            intent.setComponent(new ComponentName("com.miui.securitycenter", "com.miui.permcenter.autostart.AutoStartManagementActivity"));
        } else if ("oppo".equalsIgnoreCase(manufacturer)) {
            intent.setComponent(new ComponentName("com.coloros.safecenter", "com.coloros.safecenter.permission.startup.StartupAppListActivity"));
        } else if ("vivo".equalsIgnoreCase(manufacturer)) {
            intent.setComponent(new ComponentName("com.vivo.permissionmanager", "com.vivo.permissionmanager.activity.BgStartUpManagerActivity"));
        } else if ("Letv".equalsIgnoreCase(manufacturer)) {
            intent.setComponent(new ComponentName("com.letv.android.letvsafe", "com.letv.android.letvsafe.AutobootManageActivity"));
        } else if ("Honor".equalsIgnoreCase(manufacturer)) {
            intent.setComponent(new ComponentName("com.huawei.systemmanager", "com.huawei.systemmanager.optimize.process.ProtectActivity"));
        }

        List<ResolveInfo> list = getPackageManager().queryIntentActivities(intent, PackageManager.MATCH_DEFAULT_ONLY);

        if  (list.size() > 0) {
            startActivity(intent);
        }

} catch (Exception e) {
        Log.e("exc" , String.valueOf(e));
}
```

But it's not working on new devices. (Realme, Oppo, etc)

Comment: is it working with Xiaomi ?

Comment: yes, it works with Xiaomi, but the rest of the devices are not.

Comment: Thanks for the info, I have also same problem

Comment: @user12272459 is there any solution for this issue ?

Comment: @Eren Tüfekçi  is there any solution for this auto start issue?